# C# WPF - DataTable to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to Fetch 80K users from SQL. Is there a way to directly convert DataTable object to ObservableCollection because it takes too much time on the `foreach` loop?

```
private void FetchRelay(object obj)
{

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
    dt = new DataTable();

    conn.Open();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    conn.Close();

    UserList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        UserList.Add(new Person((int)row[0], (string)row[1], (string)row[2]));

    }
}
```

Comment: `80K` you shouldn't and only read those data in junks eg. implement paging. defered scrolling. or other datagrid mechanism to only load data if actually requested. BUT to answer your question you should consider consuming the executereader yourself instead of letting the datatable do it - here you may fnd demo code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader

Comment: I would also recommand using an ORM (object relational mapping) like Entity Framework Core that abstracts the SQL layer and you directly work with objects. here you may find a demo: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli

Comment: much more likely it is select query which takes too much time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all replies, here is my solution. Hope it will help someone.
Firstly, loading to the DataTable object and re-reading from it takes too much time. Instead, I use the reader.

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                 while (reader.Read())
                    {}
}
```

Secondly, I created a thread, that works on background, so that it won't freeze  the GUI.

```
public void newMethod(object obj)
    {

        Thread th = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            //read SQL, place into ObservableColl
        });
        th.start();
```

Lastly, when I add to ObservableCollection directly, GUI (Devexpress Grid Control) couldn't catch the ObsCol. Elements were entering one by one. To solve the issue, I created a second ObservableCollection and added to it. Then, assigned NewCollection to the main one.

```
public void newMethod(object obj)
    {Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                NewList.Clear();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    NewList.Add(new Person((int)reader[0], reader[1].ToString(), reader[2].ToString()));
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
            UserListNotCollection = new ObservableCollection<Person>(NewList);
        });
        newThread.Start();
```

Further readings [Manage Multi-Thread Data Updates](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/11765/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/performance-improvement/manage-multi-thread-data-updates)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

- Create a "constructor" of type `Task<Person>` called "`TaskOfNewPerson`";
- Create a `List<Task<Person>>()` right after you load your datatable called "`lstTaskOfNewPerson`";
- Then, for each row in datatable,

  ```
  `lstTaskOfNewPerson.add(Person.TaskOfNewPerson((int)row[0], (string)row[1], (string)row[2])))`;
  ```
- Finally, when everything was processed, get the result:

  ```
   `await Task.WhenAll(lstTaskOfNewPerson);`
  ```

And you can also get the results in the `ObservableCollection` using a loop for each Task in lstTaskOfNewPerson like this:

```
                foreach (Task<Person> personin lstTaskOfNewPerson)
                {
                    if (person.Result != null)
                    {
                        var resPerson = person.Result;
                        (...)
                    }
                }
```

Comment: it looks to me that for some reason you assume that the bottleneck is in Person class contructor. it is very unlikely. and even if it is so, using 80K Tasks is not the best solution

Comment: If not, it is (and yes, I assumed it was), then you should page the "script" and create Tasks for each of the results obtained.